# позиционирование слайдера

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой слайдер. Span'ы по бокам отображают значение.
При выборе более 10 (слева) значение spana увеличивается до 2-ух знаков и толкает слайдер. И получается при переходе с 9 на 10 слайдер "дрыгается".
Как этого избежать? при выборе position:absolute слайдер перекрывает span'ы.

Код

```
<div class="oneline">
    <span id="leftSetNicotineSlider" >0</span>
    <input id="nicotineSlider" name="nicotine" type="text" class="slider" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="45" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,45]" />
    <span id="rightSetNicotineSlider" >45</span>
</div>
```

Comment: задать спанам с цифрами например `min-width` с шириной соотв. двум цифрам в ряд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте спанам:

```
width: 30px; условно
text-align: center; 
z-inedx: 100;
```

на тот случай если `position absolute`, как вы писали выше.